# Codeigniter form_dropdown issue for value and css

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

i use a form_dropdown to select a day to show some programs which are incluted at this day.My code is:

```
echo form_dropdown('date_id',$dayslist);
```

With this code after i press the submit button the dropdown displays the selected day. When i change my code and add code for css class like this:

```
 echo form_dropdown('date_id',$dayslist,'','class ="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn-default"');
```

the dropdown form displays the day that return at first time from the database instead the selected day. Any solution about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i have change my code to:

```
echo form_dropdown('date_id',$dayslist,array(),'class ="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn-default"');
```

Instead of:

```
 echo form_dropdown('date_id',$dayslist,'','class ="form-control selectpicker" data-style="btn-default"');
```

and it is work perfect